# Color bar graph according to grouping variable

Tags: r, colors, boxplot

I have been looking for some time on stack, but no answer correspond directly to what i am looking for.

I want to plot some results in a bar graph, and color the bars according to the grouping values in another column of my dataset. So, column 1 is the grouping variable ("v" and "d"), and column 2 is the plotted value. I am trying to make a list out of column 1 that I could use as a color argument, but I can't find a way to define that exactly.

```
status  diff

d   -2141,5

v   510

d   -947

v   867

d   -960,5

v   903

d   -421

v   1285,5

d   -1155

v   556,5
```

Thanks !

Comment: Here are two options:  default colours `barplot(dat$diff, col=dat$status)`, or create a vector of colours for the grouping variable `barplot(dat$diff, col=ifelse(dat$status=="v", "green", "blue"))`

Comment: This can be achieved using `library(ggplot2)` fairly easily. [Here are some examples](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use a named vector to define the colors, which you can index with the levels of the factor (this assumes the grouping column is a factor; otherwise it must be a character vector, in which case it could be used as the index argument directly):

```
df <- data.frame(status=c('d','v','d','v','d','v','d','v','d','v'), diff=c(-2141.5,510,-947,867,-960.5,903,-421,1285.5,-1155,556.5) );
cols <- c(d='red',v='green');
barplot(df$diff,col=cols[levels(df$status)[df$status]]);
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: Thank you ! Apparently ggplot2 also allows to make some nice plots, I should look into it.